# How to calculate the roll sum without summing the current date?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

| var 1 | Day |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 0 | 7 |
| 0 | 8 |

I would like to calculate k-days rollsum without accounting for the current day.
For example,

3-days rollsum will be calculated as below:

| var 1 | Day | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | NA |
| 0 | 2 | NA |
| 1 | 3 | NA |
| 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 | 2 |
| 1 | 6 | 3 |
| 0 | 7 | 3 |
| 0 | 8 | 2 |

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say 3-days rollsum do you mean previous 3 days (as supplied in Day column) or previous 3 rows?

Comment: previous 3 days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use any of the rolling function with `k = 3` and `lag` the result by 1 step.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

k <- 3

df %>% mutate(sum = lag(rollsumr(var1, k, fill = NA)))

#  var1 Day sum
#1    0   1  NA
#2    0   2  NA
#3    1   3  NA
#4    1   4   1
#5    1   5   2
#6    1   6   3
#7    0   7   3
#8    0   8   2
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(var1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Day = 1:8), 
row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `stats::filter`:

```
df <- structure(list(var1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Day = 1:8), 
                row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")

df$sum <- stats::filter(df$var1, c(0, 1, 1, 1), sides = 1)
#  var1 Day sum
#1    0   1  NA
#2    0   2  NA
#3    1   3  NA
#4    1   4   1
#5    1   5   2
#6    1   6   3
#7    0   7   3
#8    0   8   2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using embed

```
> roll=3
> c(rep(NA,roll),rowSums(embed(df$var1,roll+1)[,-1]))
[1] NA NA NA  1  2  3  3  2
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** We have provided `dat` reproducibly in the Note at the end.

If you can avoid using `lag` I would because if you have dplyr loaded it will clobber R's `lag` and even worse the direction of the lag is opposite so the result is fragile depending on what is loaded.  This avoids that. Sum over 4 values and subtract the current value.  This will work with or without dplyr loaded.  If dplyr is loaded optionally replace `transform` with `mutate`.

```
library(zoo)

k <- 3
transform(dat, sum = rollsumr(var_1, k + 1, fill = NA) - var_1)
##   var_1 Day sum
## 1     0   1  NA
## 2     0   2  NA
## 3     1   3  NA
## 4     1   4   1
## 5     1   5   2
## 6     1   6   3
## 7     0   7   3
## 8     0   8   2
```

**2)** Another possibility is to use the fact that `rollapplyr` supports a vector of offsets.  Use a list containing that vector.  The result is the same as (1).

```
library(zoo)
k <- 3
transform(dat, sum = rollapplyr(var_1, list(-seq(k)), sum, fill = NA))
```

**3)** The `Day` column has consecutive values in the example but if it did not then this would work (and also works if they are consecutive). It is based on the fact that `rollapplyr` accepts a list of offset vectors.

```
library(zoo)

k <- 3
w <- with(dat, seq_along(Day) - findInterval(Day - k, Day)) # widths
transform(dat, sum = rollapplyr(var_1, lapply(-w, seq, to = -1), sum, fill = NA))
```

### Note

```
dat <- data.frame(var_1 = rep(c(0, 1, 0), c(2, 4, 2)), Day = 1:8)
```